# Run SQL Update Query on basis on SELECT query result (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

Good Afternoon All,

I'm currently mid-migration from an **MS Access DB** to a **MySQL DB**.  Originally we had a field which was a multiple-select drop down list in Outlook, so the "Category" field contains multiple values and string values at that, which even with my best DBA hat on I know won't work.

What I'm trying to do is write a load of migration scripts effectively, so for starters write a select query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_clients where category like "%Newsletter%"
```

Then, I want to take the results of that, and almost in a do... while fashion,  for each result run something like

`SQL CREATE in table tbl_Client_Category_Assoc where ClientID is tbl_Clients.ClientID and Where CategoryID is 1`

Please could anyone offer any assistance?

Many Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sounds like you need to build query that expands the multi-value field to multiple records. Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-multivalued-fields-7C2FD644-3771-48E4-B6DC-6DE9BEBBEC31#bm7